# zsh - where and which give different results on the first line

Tags: zsh, path

I'm using zsh and have 2 `ipython` executables in my `$PATH`:

```
❯ which ipython
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/ipython
❯ where ipython
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tg/bin/ipython
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/ipython
```

As you can see, `where` and `which` give different results on the first line, why is that?

Comment: Hmm, usually with zsh `where` is just `whence -ca` and `which` is `whence -c`. Have you aliased either? What's the result of `where where` and `where which`?

Comment: @frabjous No, they're both zsh builtins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to looking for external executables `where`, aka `whence -ca` does a full `$PATH` look-up for the command, while `which` aka `whence -c` relies on cached data (as exposed by the `$commands` special associative array).

If the `/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tg/bin/ipython` file was added after the cache was built, it will be missed by `whence`.

Doing a `hash -r` / `rehash` will invalidate that cache and you'll likely find that after that `where` and `which` agree. See [the code](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/41eb200d66e4bea7bc5798888a1755cdf5daa3b0/Src/builtin.c#L3928) for details.